# Is there a way of converting voice memos to text?

Tags: macos, voice-dictation, voice-memo

I would like to record some notes with Voice Memos and transcribe that to text when the time comes.

It seems that since both are part of macOS, there must be a way of linking the two. Failing that is there an open source solution?

Using an M1 Mac Mini with macOS Ventura.

Answer (score 1):

There are many services, my favorite being [Otter.ai](https://otter.ai/).

**Apple Way**

You can use Apple Dictation to perform this task. Here is the great and detailed article on the subject:

[How to transcribe audio to text using Dictation on a Mac](https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blog/2022/how-transcribe-audio-text-using-dictation-on-mac).

**Google Way**

Use Google Docs if you have [free] Google account.

Just open Google Docs and select Voice Typing, then start your Voice Memo. Google shall transcribe everything into text.

[Official Google Docs Help for Voice Typing](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/4492226?hl=en)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've used [Just Press Record](https://apps.apple.com/gb/app/just-press-record/id1033342465) in the past on iOS, although it's also the recording app, not just for transcription. They have a macOS version too. The transcription is good.

It will import audio files from other applications also (not mp3 for some reason), and will automatically transcribe them. It records to wav, aiff or m4a, so I assume the import formats are also the same, though I can't find any docs on that.

It has a neat trick of highlighting each word as the audio plays back.

Overall a nice app!

Answer (score 0):

I use [Textify](https://apps.apple.com/ch/app/textify-lesen-statt-h%C3%B6ren/id1207383840) for this. Does the job reasonably well, but the result usually needs editing.